# Who is the adi buddha?

Tags: history

- In many web sites they are saying that there is another buddha and he is the incarnation of lord vishnu and he existed before lord buddha existed.
  **My Question**
- Were there two buddhas ?
- Was he an incarnation of lord vishnu ?
- Was his teachings same as lord buddhas teachings ?

Comment: This question is an attempt to propagate Hindu beliefs

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Were there two buddhas ?

There are not just one, nor two, but many many buddhas in all directions of the cosmos, literally speaking.

> Was he an incarnation of lord vishnu ?

"adi-buddha" belongs to the Tibetan Buddhism, maybe related to the Tibetan's rooted religion, Bon. "adi-buddha", thus completely confusing here how does an Indian god related.

> Was his teachings same as lord buddhas teachings ?

No. I think in the "adi-buddha" related faculty no record showed what he taught.

If you are interested in Buddhism, read some fundamental sutras such as the Heart Sutra. Buddhism is about how to end the suffering and be truly liberated from life. It's not about supernatural, mystic, magic, spell, voodoo power that sorts of things.

Comment: so gautama buddha was lord vishnu

Comment: @sakthi If you do read my answer, I'm completely speechless that you've drawn such your conclusion. I'm sure the other readers have my clear answer. This is an open platform, question and answer are to serve all people interested in Buddhism. And my task here is to provide what I know as much clear and accurate, for those studying authentic Buddhist Teaching. I don't know your purpose maybe you have an interest in promoting your Hindu gods?

Answer (score 1):

In Buddhism, the Buddha is unrelated to Vishnu (refer to this [link](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/narada/nutshell.html)),which states:

> *The Buddha is neither an incarnation of the Hindu God Vishnu, as is believed by some, nor is He a savior who freely saves others by His
>   personal salvation. The Buddha exhorts His disciples to depend on
>   themselves for their deliverance, for both purity and defilement
>   depend on oneself. Clarifying His relationship with His followers and
>   emphasizing the importance of self-reliance and individual striving,
>   the Buddha plainly states: "You should exert yourselves, the
>   Tathagatas (Buddhas) are only teachers.*

In fact, in the oldest Pali scriptures, it appears Vishnu is not mentioned at all because the primary Brahmanistic gods mentioned were Indra, Brahma & Prajapati.

About the Vedas that existed during the Buddha's life, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu) states:

> *Vishnu is a Vedic deity, but not a prominent one when compared to Indra, Agni and others. Just 5 out of 1028 hymns of the Rigveda, a 2nd
>   millennium BCE Hindu text, are dedicated to Vishnu, and he finds minor
>   mention in the other hymns.*

The idea that the Buddha was a reincarnation of Vishnu is strictly [from Hinduism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha_in_Hinduism) and part of the assimilation of Buddhism into Hinduism, which made Buddhism extinct in India.

Comment: what about ADI-BUDDHA

Comment: never head of him or her. refer to google

Answer (score 0):

Adi Buddha is the first primordial Buddha. The trikaya consists of dharmakaya (truth), sambhogakaya (bliss), nirmanakaya (emanation). Adi Buddha is particularly known for emanating the universe. Buddhahood is neither god nor man. All devas (including Vishnu) in Buddhism  are created and impermanent. All Buddhas teach the same thing, although they might teach it in a different way.

Comment: Can you please add which Buddhism school(s) hold this view?